# Word wrap for console output

Tags: linux, eclipse, console, word-wrap

I am using Eclipse and the word wrap feature is nice, but it can be hard to figure out where one line starts and the other ends. Is there an elegant way to handle this? Can I make every other fully wrapped line say have a light grey background? Other options? In window->preferences->run/debug->console the options seem very limited. I can't even change the size of my text?

Comment: I don't think there is much that can be changed here. The font is in the Preferences in General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts - Debug > Console font.